# XCode - Storeyboard scene background image from assets.xcassets

Tags: xcode, storyboard, xcasset

I have a storeyboard scene and an image set called LaunchImage in assets.xcassets My question is how do I use this LaunchImage in my storeyboard scene so it the background image of this scene?

Answer (score 0):

Add an uIImageView to your storyboard scene. 
and in the image property of this image set "LaunchImage".
you will need to properly set your UIImageView constraints.

Comment: how do I set UIImageView constraints?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_auto_layout/chapters/pin-constraints.html

Comment: Where do I set the image to LaunchImage? can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: I get this error when I set the image value to LaunchImage ` NewProject[1038:301362] Could not load the "LaunchImage" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier `

Comment: Please help @LastMove

Comment: The filesystem on iOS devices is case sensitive, so it's quite possibly a case issue.